# Couldn't find element with Splinter, tried all methods and returns empty string every time

Tags: python, python-3.x, splinter

I'm trying to click a "Next" button and I can't find it by either text nor XPath, class, or other methods. I've also tried to return all the elements from the bigger list of elements and it's not there either.

I don't know exactly what's wrong and why it's not there.

HTML:

```
<div class="topnav clearfix">
    <div class="toptotal">Viewing 1 - 10</div>
    <div class="pos-right">
        <span class="page-start" style="width:53px">Previous</span>
        <span class="page-cur">1</span> 
        <a class="list_goto_page" data="2" href="javascript:void(0);">2</a>                
        <span class="page-break">...</span>
        <a class="list_goto_page" data="117" href="javascript:void(0);">117</a> 
        <a class="page-next list_goto_page" data="2" href="javascript:void(0);">Next</a>
    </div>
```

PYTHON CODE:

```
browser.visit(link)
time.sleep(2)

nb = browser.find_by_xpath(xpath='//div[@class="topnav clearfix"]//a')
print nb
```

RESULT:

```
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Work\Machine Learning\bot\bot.py", line 24, in <module>
    nb.first.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\splinter\element_list.py", line 53, in first
    return self[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\splinter\element_list.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    self.find_by, self.query))
splinter.exceptions.ElementDoesNotExist: no elements could be found with xpath "//div[@class="topnav clearfix"]//a"
```

I want it to find and click on the element, so it can go to the next page. But instead, I get an empty list of elements. What did I do wrong and how can it be fixed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the element I was trying to find was embedded in an iframe and I had first to get access to it in order to find the element I was looking for.